# Show custom 403 error page based on content-type

Tags: nginx

I currently have the following nginx configuration to show a custom 403 error page:

```
server
{
...

error_page   403  /forebidden.html;
location = /forebidden.html {
    root   /path/to/root/;
}

...

)
```

My question is,
is there a way to use this custom error page based on a conten-type?
For example, if the content type is "application/json", don't use the custom page but instead show the default nginx error page.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration below return a `forebidden.json` if `Accept: application/json` presented in request headers, otherwise `forebidden.html` by default.

```
map $http_accept $my_error_type {
    default "html";
    "application/json" "json";
}

server {
...
    error_page  403  /forebidden.$my_error_type;
...
}
```